# Find synomyms in the document and replace them

Tags: r, quanteda

Using the `replace()` option of quanteda is their any automated way to find synonyms in the text and replace them with the same word?

For example use treasure option of `remove tokens`?

Example input:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c("I try to find synonym words", "I am interesting to detect equivalent phrases", "Finally, please find another option for metonym"), strinsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Detect the words which have synonyms from thesaurus or wordnet and replace them in text but also keep one column which will have the token which is the initial word and another with the synonym which replaced it. Is it possible to test it also for unigram and bigram?
Example of expected output:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), word_for_repale = c("synonym", "equivalent", "metonym"), synonym = c("synonym", "synonym", "synonym"), text = c("I try to find synonym words", "I am interesting to detect equivalent phrases", "Finally, please find another option for metonym"), strinsAsFactors+ = FALSE)
```

Comment: If you have the synomyms in a data.frame you can use the dfm_replace function to replace them. `dfm_replace(dfm, pattern = syn$synonym, replacement = syn$replacement)`. If you want to find synonyms then the question is which synonym? You could use wordnet to find synomyms, choose one and built a data.frame out of it, but if you have a large text, this process will take a while. There are a few SO answers about this.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you are seeking to do, and provide an example? Expected output would be useful too.

Comment: @KenBenoit thankk you. I made an update to the question